# Will Excel macros continue or slow down after pc "screen-off" only not standby?

Tags: microsoft-word, sleep, macros

I'm running a large macro in Excel, and leaving it on all night.

I realize that if your computer goes into sleep mode, it may pause the macro processing, but I didn't think that when the ["screen turns off"](https://imgur.com/T3TqZsO) it would slow/pause the macro processing.

However, I started a simple forward loop in Word (Excel is hung up right now) that I estimated to take about 100 minutes (based on loops of a lesser magnitude), and then left (allowing my screen to turn off *without* sleeping).

I just returned 3 hours later, and my Word macro is still going. This makes me very confident that my screen turning off slows down my macro, but I really didn't expect this to be the result.

So now I am asking the community if this is true: That a macro will slow/pause itself if the screen turns off (without sleeping).

Many thanks beforehand to answers

Answer (score 1):

If the screen is the only thing going to sleep, then no, that won't
affect your macro.

However, computers are sometimes set up to go to sleep in stages. First
the screen, then maybe after an hour the computer, too. It all depends
on the settings.

So, you want to check those settings. On Windows 7 I found them under
Control Panel, Hardware and Sound, Power Options. Another way is to open
the Start menu and type `sleep`.